# Calculate padding on coordinates bounding box

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I'm working on a GIS application and I can't seem to warp my head around this problem.
I have bounding box defined as 4 coordinates pair (A, B, C, D in the picture) and a center and I want to calculate a new bounding box (A', B', C', D' in the picture) defined as the original bounding box, plus a padding on all sides. The padding value is defined as a percentage of the longest side of the original bounding box `P`.

What I'm trying to achieve is: given `A, B, C, D, CENTER` and a percentage value `P`, calculate `A', B', C', D'`.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Here is a picture of this for reference:

[image]

Comment: Are the sides short enough you do not need to worry about change to the latitude in the region of the (padded) box?

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm not sure I understand, you mean the switch from positive to negative and vice versa ?

Comment: No, I mean the change in the length of a degree of longitude as the latitude changes. If the region is small you can consider the latitude constant. If the region is large the factor varies between the North and South ends and you have to account for it.

Comment: @RossMillikan oh i get it.  The bounding box can be really big so yeah would be better to account for it

Comment: Big is in relation to the 4000 mile radius of the earth, so 100 miles is still small.  The geometry is much easier if you can just use a local Cartesian frame accounting for the shortening of a degree of longitude as 1 nautical mile times the sine of the latitude.  If you want real accuracy, you need to worry about the earth not being spherical and the fact that there are no parallel lines on the surface of a sphere.  Also are the sides oriented NS and EW, or can they be at an angle?  Are they parallel?

Comment: @RossMillikan I misunderstood the scale then, 100 mile would be around the maximum value of the bounding box in either direction. So I guess no need to worry about that. The side NS and ES are always parallel in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can erect a local Cartesian coordinate system if the area is small.  Small here is relative to the radius of the earth, about $4000$ miles ($6400$ km).  You can use the center as the origin.  The origin has latitude $\phi$ and longitude $\lambda$ and local coordinates $(0,0)$.  Distances North/South come from the fact that one degree of latitude corresponds to a distance of $\frac {R_e \pi}{180}$.  Distances East/West come from the fact that one degree of longitude corresponds to a distance of $\frac {R_e \pi}{180}\cos(\phi)$.  The earth radius varies, but for a spherical earth you choose one value and use it consistently.  Most often I have seen the equatorial radius used, $R_e=6378 km \approx 3963 mi$.

The dimensions of the box are then $\frac {R_e \pi}{180}\Delta \phi$, North/South where $\Delta \phi$ is the difference in latitude between the top and the bottom in degrees and $\frac {R_e \pi}{180}\cos \phi \Delta \lambda$ East/West.  You can find the linear distance you want to pad and convert back to the change in latitude/longitude

Comment: thanks ! Could you provide the operation to convert back to the change in lat/lng ? Perhaps an example ?

Comment: If the physical East/West distance is $d$, we have $d=\frac {R_e\pi}{180}\cos \phi \Delta \lambda$, so $\Delta \lambda = \frac{180d}{R_e \pi \cos \phi}$.  It is just algebra to invert the equation